# Single slit intererometry

Tags: waves, interference, wave-particle-duality

I recently discovered that firing a single particle through a single slit counter-intuitively results in an interference pattern (over multiple trials of course). I looked through the Q/As that i could find on the site here but none seemed to address *why* this happens.

I was looking at [this article](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m309-03a/m309-projects/krzak/) which mentions that there are multiple "aperture" points of the wave at the slit (in a vacuum i assume). What i'm confused about is why this happens and what determines the amount of aperture points.

The sources i find seem to say there is an arbitrary? discreet number of source points for a single particle wave. One might think that as the number of source points approaches infinity (ie. continuum) the interference pattern disappears, so finding the interference pattern means there has to be a set number of discreet source points.

What determines the number of source points and where those source points are located? Why are they at the slit and not everywhere?

Also, the results of the experiment seem to imply that the wave originates from sources points at the slit (that seemingly would be located at varying distances from the wave's original source point), simultaneously. See the following image:

[image]

The points of "a", are located a different distances from the wave's original point of origination. Which doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: It is really saying that the scattering at the edges of the slit can be modeled as point sources. these will interfere with each other. this link may help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslitd.html

Comment: Link doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: Hi Yogi, yeah someone is asleep at the wheel maintaining an otherwise good site, its been hit and miss for the last 3 weeks. I got on using the link below,  if you do then try to navigate from there. No guarantees though  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuccon.html

Comment: @anna v Finally got onto that link and unless i'm missing something i don't think that really addresses the questions i had.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave_expansion .  The neighboring sources overlap and approximate the plane wave locally, at the edges there is no more light so that last source is not overlapped and generates the spherical wave which will interfere with the plane wave.